# how to get the attribute values of the table row using jquery?

Tags: jquery, attributes

I have a following razor to create a table.

```
@model IEnumerable<iBoxV5.Model.Common.AdvancedSearch>
<table id="SearchFieldsTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>
        ColumnName
    </th>
    <th>
        FilterValues
    </th>
    <th>Updated Before</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr ColumnName=@item.ColumnName DatabaseColumn=@item.DatabaseColumn DisplayName=@item.DisplayName Datatype=@item.Datatype id=@(index++)>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ColumnName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.FilterValue, new { @class = "FrmTextBox advSearch" });

        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.FilterValue, new { @class = "FrmTextBox advSearch" });
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.FilterValueTo, new { @class = "FrmTextBox advSearch" });
    </td>
</tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

And In the above I have added few attributes for the  like ColumnName.

I wants to build a JSON for the each row of the Table.

I tried with the following jquery Snippet.

```
var SearchFieldsTable = $("#SearchFieldsTable tbody");

var trows = SearchFieldsTable[0].rows;

$.each(trows, function (index, row) {
    var ColumnName=$(row).attr("ColumnName");
});
```

But the above is not returning the ColumnName I expected.

Comment: Please post the rendered markup instead of serverside codes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this;

```
$("#trowId").attr("attrbuteName");
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get the value by either class or id like

```
var ColumnName=$(row).attr(".ColumnName").val();
```

or

```
var ColumnName=$(row).attr("#ColumnName").val();
```

Answer (score 2):

May be this will be helpful.

```
var SearchFieldsTable = $("#SearchFieldsTable tbody");

var trows = SearchFieldsTable.children("tr");

$.each(trows, function (index, row) {
    var ColumnName=$(row).attr("ColumnName");
    // .... Your codes here 
});
```

**FYI:**
"tbody" don't have "rows". The following is wrong

```
SearchFieldsTable[0].rows
```

You can use the following code instead to use above code.

```
var SearchFieldsTable = $("#SearchFieldsTable");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a local variable in each iteration, now your ColumnName variable only stores the attribute of last row. Also `ColumnName` in not a valid attribute. You can use [`data-*`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) attributes and `map` method.

```
var columnName = $("#SearchFieldsTable tbody tr").map(function(){
                      return $(this).data('ColumnName')
                 })
```

Now columnName is an array of column names.

- [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)
- [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers won't support custom attributes. So, you can better use `data()`.

```
var ColumnName = $(row).data("ColumnName");
```

And in the row, define it as:

```
<tr data-ColumnName=@item.ColumnName ...
```